# How to get apdu command logs from ingenico device in c?

Tags: c, apdu, contactless-smartcard, emv, tlv

I am working on Ingedev to implement a Telium application in `C`.

How can I read the Application Protocol Data Unit (APDU) from a contactless EMV card transaction with an Ingenico device?

Can the APDU be retrieved from the TLV tree data exchanged between the device and the card? If so, how would this be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KJ, 
to view APDU commands, you have two options :

- If you are developing the embedded software running on the terminal, enable logging for your ContactLess kernel, then collect the logs from your Ingenico terminal.
- If you don't have access to the embedded software, you'll need a third party contactless sniffer, like [Fime SmartSpy](https://www.fime.com/products/transaction-spies/smartspy-contactless.html). It will record the exact transaction, and will let you analyze in details the ADPUs and the whole dialog.